# Problem about measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f,g$ belong to $M^{+}$, let $\varphi$ be a simple function in $M^{+}$ with 
$\varphi\leqslant{f}$, and let $\omega$ be a simple function in $M^{+}$ with 
$\omega\leqslant{f+g}$. Put $\theta_{1}=\inf\lbrace{\omega, \varphi}\rbrace$ and $\theta_{2}=\sup\lbrace\omega-\varphi,0\rbrace$. Show that 
$\omega=\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}$ and that $\theta_{1}\leqslant{f}$ and
$\theta_{2}\leqslant{g}$.

If $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a measurable space then

$M^{+} = \lbrace{f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}\,:\, f\,\,\mbox{es}\,\,\Sigma\mbox{-measurable} } \,\,
\mbox{and}\,\,\mbox{non negative}\rbrace$

I have been able to prove that $\omega=\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}$ and that $\theta_{1}\leqslant{f}$, but I have not been able to prove that $\theta_{2}\leqslant{g}$.
Could anyone help me with those part of the problem?

Comment: What's meant with $\inf\{\omega,\varphi\}$? Is it $\min(\omega,\varphi)$ pointwise?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Either we are missing something or $\theta_2 \leq g$ just isn't true. Take $f \equiv g \equiv 1$, $\phi \equiv \frac14$ and $\omega \equiv \frac74$. Then $\theta_2 \equiv \frac74 - \frac14 = \frac32 > 1 = g$.